# How to clear UINavigationController's viewControllers when I set window.rootViewController with a new UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

My English is bad,so my expression might not clear,sorry.
I show my Code direct:
appdelegate.m

```
Dly_navigationController* rootVC = nil;

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loginFlag"] != nil) {
    HS_HomeViewController* homeVC = [[HS_HomeViewController alloc] init];
    rootVC = [[Dly_navigationController  alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
}
else {
    HS_LoginViewController* loginVC = [[HS_LoginViewController alloc] init];
    rootVC = [[Dly_navigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
}
self.window.rootViewController = rootVC;
```

I want to login when my app is running.I do that:

```
- (void)gotoLogin {

    HS_LoginViewController *tmpLogin = [[HS_LoginViewController alloc] init];
    Dly_navigationController* rootView = [[Dly_navigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tmpLogin];
    AppDelegate *thisDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    [thisDelegate.window setRootViewController:rootView]; 
}
```

it works good,but the old rootViewController and other old VCs don't release.This gives me a bad impact on subsequent operations.For instance,the Notification's things.

Thanks for reading my question and my broken English.

Comment: Use `pushViewController:` or `presentViewControlelr:` instead of `initWithRootViewController`. Hope help you

Comment: @SeraZheng Sorry for that way don't work,thank you for your answer.Wish you happiness.

Comment: What third-party SDKs did you use?And did you use blocks?

Comment: @Lumialxk Thank you ,I solved this problem.This is a circling reference.Thank for everyone.Good luck for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ARC，When you assign window's rootViewController to other viewController, there is no strong reference to the old rootViewController.
If old rootViewController not dealloc, it is possible there is a strong reference cycles, so I think you should review your implements of HS_HomeViewController class to find out this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!I solved this problem after get your suggestion!Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, Use only single navigation controller with Push another view controllers.

Set LoginVC as root of navigation. Then on `DidLoad` of LoginVC, check with if user is logged in. If valid login then simply push controller with animated **NO**. By this, user'll not get any effect and directly move to HomeVC. Same you can manage on `validLogin` method of Login. Here you can push with animation.

In this case, if you want to logout from anywhere of application, root will be LoginVC.

Please maintain your `NavigationBar` as per your need.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
HS_LoginViewController* loginVC = [[HS_LoginViewController alloc] init];
Dly_navigationController* rootVC = [[Dly_navigationController  alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];

self.window.rootViewController = rootVC;
```

**Login Page**

```
AppDelegate *thisDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     thisDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

     if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loginFlag"] != nil) {

         HS_HomeViewController* homeVC = [[HS_HomeViewController alloc] init];
         [thisDelegate.rootVC pushViewController:homeVC animated:false];
     }
     //... Your Code
}

- (void)validLogin
{
     //Set your Login flag with defaults
     HS_HomeViewController* homeVC = [[HS_HomeViewController alloc] init];
     [thisDelegate.rootView pushViewController:homeVC animated:true];
}
```

Hope, my scenario will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Your suggestion give me another way to fimish my app，I will try that you suggested，thank you very much！

Answer (score 0):

I think there is strong reference cycles in your code, you can use the analyze tool to find out the problem.

Comment: YES，you are right，I  find my HomeVC reference number is 6 after navigationcontroller release by 'po HomeVC.retainCount'.Thank you for your answer!Good luck for you!